# Create an AIF Service in C#

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

I know how to invoke/call an AIF service from managed code.
I have seen examples of how to create custom services in X++.

What I would like to know is whether I can create a service in C#
using the visual studio integration. In other words, my implementation of 
the custom service is in C#, I will use whatever tables/queries I need to use 
using the .NET/VS integration.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

An AIF service need a X++ class extending [AifDocumentService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aifdocumentservice.aspx) and must have methods in order to attach the service operations to the methods.

The service methods may call C# methods thus acting as a proxy, but must nonetheless conform to the base class; `findKeys` must return a `AifEntityKeyList` etc.

If you want a document service returning AX data, it would be an uphill battle to code it in C#.

[image]